# Is it correct to use "had to" in result clause of a conditional sentence?

Tags: conditional-constructions

Which one is appropriate...

If you had not paid fine, I would have had to pay.

Or,

If you had not paid fine, I had to pay.

Comment: Thank you sir, Is the first sentence correct? Is the first one is third conditional or perfect conditional?

Answer (score 1):

Like FumbleFingers said in the comments, this question should be moved to the English Language Learners website. Here's a quick answer to your question until then.

First, the verb "to have" is used in many ways in English. One way is to make verb tenses, such as:

> I had not paid the fine yet.

Another use of "to have" is similar to saying "must." For example:

> I had to pay the fine.

Your first sentence is almost correct. It is a third (past unreal) conditional. You could say:

> If you had not paid the fine, I would have had to pay it.

This uses "to have" twice but for different reasons.